# Trying to run truffle and it says command not found on my mac

Tags: npm-install, truffle

I've been trying to start Truffle but when I do `$ truffle` it says command not found. I've done `npm init`, `npm i truffle` and `./node_modules/.bin/truffle init` but nothing works. I have the latest version of node but it still makes no difference.

```
Roberts-MacBook-Pro-9:~ rbeit$ truffle init
-bash: truffle: command not found
Roberts-MacBook-Pro-9:~ rbeit$ truffle
-bash: truffle: command not found
Roberts-MacBook-Pro-9:~ rbeit$
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only installed the truffle npm locally, you can ether install it globally with `npm install -g truffle` or call it from npm by adding

```
  "scripts": {
    "truffle": "truffle init",
  }
```

to your package.json

and call it like this `npm run truffle`

Comment: I did all that and when I did the command truffle or truffle test it still says command not found.